# What do I need to provide my team for iOS and Android development using Flutter?

Tags: xcode, flutter, gitlab

Flutter n00b here. So go easy on me ;-)

I installed Android studio on my Windows 10 PC, and started trying Flutter development.

Got to the point where I was able to publish a simple app on the Android store:

[Jake Jon Music](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noslavemedia.jakejon&hl=en&gl=US)

Easy enough. Now I want to get going with my team (3 of us).

What else do I need (hardware/software) in order to build iOS and Android apps?

Here is what I think I need so far:

1. A Mac OS Computer with Xcode to build/test/deploy to Apple App Store
2. Apple Developer Account
3. File server/NAS to store the code for the team
4. Gitlab server

Can anyone suggest anything else that is needed?

Feel free to suggest your own team setup.

Comment: You'll need a phisical IOs device, iphone or ipad.

Comment: Que chatice, but thanks...on low budget...any advice on which one I should get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few considerations:

1. You don’t need fileserver/NAS. If trying to keep costs down, you’d use some cloud-based repositories, devs would clone to their local machine, create their branches for their work on their local machines, and then regularly push back their branches to the cloud-based repo. No NAS or file server needed.
2. I am unsure by what you intended by a “GitLab server”. If you are talking about literally setting up your own server and installing GitLab on it, you really do not need to do that. I would consider taking advantage of cost-effective cloud-based solutions. You’d need quite a big team before the overhead of standing-up your own source control server starts to make sense, IMHO.
3. In terms of things that are not included in your list, I might suggest:

   - Internal project management solution (e.g., Jira, Asana, Clubhouse, etc.) to track all of the moving pieces during development project, tickets/stories, Kanban board, etc.
   - Customer service/issue management system (e.g., ZenDesk, etc.).
   - Crash reporting system (e.g., Crashlytics, Sentry, etc.).
   - With a team, a communication system other than email (e.g. Slack, Basecamp, etc.) is prudent.
   - I second Jorge’s recommendation of a wide variety of different physical devices with various OS versions for testing. There are often issues that only manifest them on physical devices (especially background services, location services, rendering artifacts on different screen sizes, etc.). Simulators only take you so far.